# The riddle in the sky

Tags: riddle

My friend did this once to me,

now I am eternally blind, you see.

I can't look at the sky at night.

It just gives me such a fright.

It brings back the memory,

of what he did to me.

And only when it is new,

Will I be able to have a midnight stroll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be

> The Moon

My friend did this once to me,

Now I am eternally blind, you see.

> Your friend 'mooned' you?

I can't look at the sky at night.

It just gives me such a fright.

It brings back the memory,

of what he did to me,

> The moon in the sky reminds you of the traumatic mooning?

And only when it is new,

Will I be able to have a midnight stroll.

> You'll be able to see by moonlight?

Comment: yup good explanation but I meant new moon not full moon oopsy. But stil it isn't ur fault so u are correct.

Answer (score 5):

I think..

> That you are a werewolf

My friend did this once to me,

> Your "friend" turned you by biting/scratching you

now I am eternally blind, you see.

> Werewolves are said to be color-blind. Also, in the series Teen Wolf, some wolves have infrared vision while others are color-blind(Alpha and Beta wolves).

I can't look at the sky at night.

It just gives me such a fright.

It brings back the memory,

of what he did to me,

> Not sure about this part, you could be traumatized and be afraid of the night sky/full moon.

And only when it is full,

Will I be able to have a midnight stroll.

> You turn into a werewolf at full moon and do stuff werewolves usually do

Comment: oops I meant new moon.

Comment: Better answer than mine!  (I like it more at least)  +1